# file with 2million rows, is it possible to create an index that will give O(1) retreival times?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, indexing

I have a file that has 2 million rows, where each row represents transactions that contain a timestamp.

I want to be able to fetch all rows that e.g. between 10:54am and 10:55am.

The rows are ordered according to time.

I cannot load the entire file in memory, is there a way to load it in memory as a batch job, then create some sort of a index that I can use to lookup the correct lines in the file for my calls?

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require other dependencies like elastic search etc.

Comment: @Phaelaxz java not javascript......

Comment: Can't you use a relational database ? If not, consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISAM

Comment: O(1) retrieval time will not be possible, unless the time to retrieve one record is the same as the time to retrieve all two million records.  Better to look for ways to reduce the overall retrieval time.

Comment: Ugh sorry, I work in both but been in javascript all morning and my brain wasn't processing.  You can read the file line by line with bufferedreader and pull out the timestamp. Use the timestamp as key in a hashmap where the value is the byte offset for that row in your file. Then you can use a RandomAccessFile. (you may need to store the length of the line to read as well as its offset)

Comment: the best I can think of is binary search for the start of timestamp and then linear to output the wanted rows ... so `O(log2(n)+m)` where n=2000000,m=size of output ... that should be relaively fast enough even without any LUT ... hope your rows are aligned to common size